# Split cells and divide a nulber of number of splits

Tags: vba, split

I am seeking your help as I am trying to obtain the following output from the raw data below.

Raw data:

```
A            B
Customer    Budget
"AAA
BBB         300
CCC"
BBB         150
"EEE
AAA"        30
```

Output desired:

```
Customer    Budget
AAA           100
BBB           100
CCC           100
BBB           150
EEE           15
AAA           15
```

Basically, I would like to split the cells which contains text on different lines (alt+enter). I have been able to split the cells and simply copy paste below using the following macro:

```
Sub SplitMacro()

'working for active sheet
'copy to the end of sheets collection

ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Dim tmpArr As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("AE1", Range("AE2").End(xlDown))
    If InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then
        tmpArr = Split(Cell, Chr(10))
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(tmpArr), 1). _
            EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown

        Cell.Resize(UBound(tmpArr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(tmpArr)
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(120, 120, 225)


    End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

However, I am have not been able to divide the Budget cells by the number of Values from column A. Any help welcome!

Many thanks

Comment: Hi, Thank you for cleaning up my message. I unfortunately can't seem to use the link you shared, the internet explorer version I am using at work is pretty old.
Anyhow, the AAA, BBB and CCC are in a unique unmerged cell and are separated by an alt+enter. The 300 value associated to it is the following cell, unmerged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line:

```
        Cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(tmpArr) + 1, 1) = Cell.Offset(, 1).Value2 / (UBound(tmpArr) + 1)
```

Just above the `End If`.

It will divide the number found in the cell to the right by the number of rows being added:

```
Sub SplitMacro()

'working for active sheet
'copy to the end of sheets collection

ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Dim tmpArr As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("AE1", Range("AE2").End(xlDown))
    If InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then
        tmpArr = Split(Cell, Chr(10))
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(tmpArr), 1). _
            EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown

        Cell.Resize(UBound(tmpArr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(tmpArr)
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(120, 120, 225)
        Cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(tmpArr) + 1, 1) = Cell.Offset(, 1).Value2 / (UBound(tmpArr) + 1)

    End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: @AlJay if this worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.